# Script to run at completion of Page Loading

Tags: javascript

On the home page I a have 2 lines of code I would like to run in JavaScript.

Where should I put these two lines of code.

Does WP have a specific way to do this.  Or should I just pick the last .js file that loads and add it there?

Comment: Depends on what the javascript is. What is it? Add the js code to your question.

Comment: it's simply to remove an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, WordPress has a function for loading javascript files:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

the last argument takes either true or false to load in the footer

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what the javascript is. What is it? Add the js code to your question.

If it's an externally loaded script that does nothing more than track page loads - like google analytics or other stat counter code - there's no reason to use wp_enqueue_script. Sometimes you can simply add it to footer.php or header.php

If you need the js to run *specifically* when the page is finished loading, then you need to wrap it in a jQuery function called `.ready()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

And if the code is jQuery, you may need to wrap it in a noConflict wrapper to prevent conflicts with other js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: that's what i ended up doing....adding it to the footer.